# Checking if excel cell has a value

Tags: php, excel

I need to dynamically generate table headings from an excel file so that the results are output in the following fashion:

Value of country1
   Value of country2
   Value of country4

If they contain a value, note that there is no country 3

Someone kindly helped me with the following script

```
// Loop the array
foreach ($vCountries as $key => $value) {
   // If value is not empty
   if (!empty($value)) {
      // display the line
      echo '<th id="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</th>'."\n";
   }
}
```

But now I need to access and check the excel spreadsheet to check if there is a value. So somehow I need to take the following code (that's my guess by the way)

```
//For example, not certain if I can use range in this context in PHP
$data->sheets[0]['cells'].range[6][9].value
```

And stick it into this statement

```
if (!empty($value)) {
```

As I have only been doing PHP for 5 days, my brains are scrambling...

Any help?

Comment: What library are you using to read the excel spreadsheet?

Comment: I think that would be good if you start by this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php.

Comment: PHP cannot natively read Excel spreadsheets, so there is no good way to do that. However, there seem to be [many](http://www.google.com/search?q=php%20excel) [libaries](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel/) to do [that](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). A solution I've used in the past is to export the spreadsheet to CSV, then use PHP's [CSV parsing functions](http://us3.php.net/str_getcsv)

Comment: @Mark I'm inheriting some code from http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader so I am taking it from there  @Murilo, thanks I'm aware of this website, unfortunately I don't have time to learn all of PHP before finishing this tool @Austin Yes I know, it doesn't hence why I'm using the existing reader and it's functions but I was wondering if you can use range in that context

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP-ExcelReader, then something like this should work

```
$sheet = 0;
$row = 6;
$col = 9;
if (array_key_exists($row,$data->sheets[$sheet]['cells']) && array_key_exists($col,$data->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$row])) {
    // cell exists
} else {
   // cell does not exist
}
```

That is basically the code used internally by PHP-ExcelReader

alternatively:

```
if(isset($data->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$row][$col]) {
    // cell exists
} else {
   // cell does not exist
}
```

**EDIT**

Hopefully there aren't any merged cells in your worksheet

Comment: Thanks Mark. I have tried the following but I am doing something wrong as I am getting a syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE error:    
    $vCountries  = array();
    foreach (vCountries  as $key => $value) {
    // If value is not empty
    $sheet = 0;
    $row = 1;
    $col = 8;
    if (array_key_exists($row,$data->sheets[$sheet]['cells']) &&    array_key_exists($col,$data->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$row])) {
    $data  .= '<th id="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</th>'."\n";
    else {
 }}
  }
    $data .= "\t</tr>\n\t\t</thead>";

Comment: Don't try to paste code in a comment (unless it's just a single line). Either edit your question and add the code, or ask another question

Comment: You also seem to be confusing my answer... I don't know what row and column you need to look at for each individual cell... the values of $sheet = 0 $row = 6 and $col = 9 are derived from your original question, but your code will need to set these values to the actual sheet, row and column that you want to look at.

Comment: And the PHP error that you're getting is because you're opening the if statement with a { but don't have a } before the else; and you have a spurious closing } later

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your replies, I will post another question because I think that what I am trying to do is not being explained very well.